# While adding ORM search filtering results based on UTC time - Odoo

Tags: odoo

I have a code that search for attendance record

`att_var1 = att_obj.search([ ('employee_id', '=', get_user_id.id), ('check_in', '>=',check_in_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')), ('check_in', '])`

Here check_in_date is a date field im adding min and max time using strftime now the results will be get for a day start to end.

But when this code executes the min time is modified based on UTC. i,e) min time is +5:30, our timezone is Asia/Kolkata and max time is also +5:30 so instead of getting a day record it fetches today 5:30 AM to tomorrow 5:30 AM

Does anyone have any knowledge about how to rectify this

i want to get data based on 00:00 to 23:59 - user timezone not UTC

Comment: Sorry i don't get it, because _your_ day is UTC+5:30 so if _you_ search in Odoo on datetime fields you will get the entries you're describing above. Probably i'm reading it wrong. It would help when you add some date you have, what your input (in gui and technically) is and what your expected result would be.